# Maven testng integration - tests outside the testng.xml are running during maven test phase

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run the test methods present inside the testng.xml only.
Maven goal-

```
test -Ptest1 -DargLine="-Dbrowser=firefox" -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

When i am trying to execute the above goal, tests present outside the testng.xml are getting executed as well.(Tests present in classes starting/ending with *Test)

```
<profile>
        <id>test1</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <echo>Using env.test1.properties</echo>
                                    <copy file="src/test/resources/env.test1.properties"
                                        tofile="src/test/resources/env.properties" overwrite="true" />
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <file>src/test/resources/testng.xml</file>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <propertyName>browser</propertyName>
                            <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>

                    </configuration>
                    <!-- <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions> -->
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

My testng.xml file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Maven tutorial" verbose="3" >
<test name="Testie">
    <!-- <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter> -->
    <classes>
        <class name="com.maven.tutorial.hello2Test"></class>

    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Testff">
    <!-- <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter> -->
    <classes>

        <class name="com.maven.tutorial.hello4Test"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

When i run the maven goal, it executes tests present in classes hello2Test,hello4Test along with other classes ending with Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 <suiteXmlFiles>
    <file>src/test/resources/testng.xml</file>
 </suiteXmlFiles>
```

to

```
 <suiteXmlFiles>
    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
 </suiteXmlFiles>
```

Comment: changing <file> to <suiteXmlFile> does not work either

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my plugin from

```
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
```

to

```
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
```